# oracle SYSDATE function not working in mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, mybatis

I am trying to use mybatis as ORM for Oracle SQL . 
I have table called login_details which has "login_time" (Timestamp(6)) column which stores timestamp.

Now I want such a records which were/are logged in  for more than 10 minutes.
So I tried a query

```
   SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE username = 'abc' AND (SYSDATE - login_time) > interval '10' MINUTE
```

which is working in DBVisualiser.
I put this query in mybatis as follows

SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE username = #{username} AND (SYSDATE - login_time) > interval '10' MINUTE

it is not working when I put it into mybatis select tag as shown above.
Instead of this , I tried

```
 SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE (TO_DATE ('06/03/2015 23:45:34' , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') - login_time) > interval '10' MINUTE
```

which works in mybatis.

It seems mybatis has problem with SYSDATE

please guide me to resolve this problem

Comment: i'm not quite familiar with mybatis, but can you try the query with a parenthesis? so it's like this `sysdate()`

Comment: *but same query donot work* is not an acceptable error. You need to explain what is the error.

Comment: @ Lalit Kumar B thanx for the reply .but there is no error displayed. But query does not returns anything

Comment: You need to escape the `<` , if inside `XML` ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the manner you are calling the `TO_DATE` function. Replace the minus sign with a comma: `TO_DATE ('6/03/2015 23:45:34', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')`.